# jquery accordion type page tab navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I have 3 tabs divs on my website, in a vertical accordeon type navigation.
when I click on a tab, the tabs changes class to "open", to appear on my page, or to disappear.

When I click on the 2nd or 3rd tab, all previous tabs changes class to "open", using prevAll function.

My issue is that when all my tabs are openned for example, and when I click on the first tab (the yellow one), I want all my previous tabs to have the "open" class removed, to prevent the yellow tab to slide under the other tabs. Same for the other tabs.

something close to this example :
https://violaineetjeremy.fr/

I can't find a way of doing tab... maybe using flags ?

here is my html :

```
<div id="spot" class="tab">

  <div class="tab_title">

  </div>

</div>

<div id="rencontres" class="tab">

  <div class="tab_title">

  </div>

</div>

<div id="shop" class="tab">

  <div class="tab_title">

  </div>

</div>
```

my CSS :

```
.tab {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(100vw - 80px);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tab_title {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 4px solid;
}

#spot {
    right: calc(-100vw + 200px);
    background-color:yellow;
}

#rencontres {
    right: calc(-100vw + 160px);
    background-color:red;
}

#shop {
    right: calc(-100vw + 120px);
    background-color:blue;

}

#spot.open {
    right: 80px;
}

#rencontres.open {
    right: 40px;
}

#shop.open {
    right: 0px;
}
```

and my Jquery

```
$(".tab:not(.open)").click(function(){

  var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("open");
  $this.prevAll(".tab").addClass("open");


});
```

and here is a jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/1eu2vsd8/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this snippet below?

It checks if the clicked tab has `class="open"`, then whether the next sibling has `class="open"` as well (which would mean it's not the focused tab). If it's not the focused tab, it closes all the following siblings; otherwise it closes itself.

If it doesn't have `class="open"`, then it removes the class from all siblings, before adding the class to itself and all previous siblings.

Although this could probably be cleaned up using multiple classes, and/or should be transitioned into using an accessible method (e.g. `aria-hidden="true"` and `aria-current="true"`), to make the page easier for accessible technologies to read.

```js
$(".tab").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
    if ($(this).next('.tab').hasClass('open')) {
      $(this).nextAll('.tab').removeClass('open');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
    }
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('.tab.open').removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('open').prevAll('.tab').addClass('open');
  };
});
```

```css
.tab {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100vw - 80px);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.tab_title {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 4px solid;
}

#spot {
  right: calc(-100vw + 200px);
  background-color: yellow;
}

#rencontres {
  right: calc(-100vw + 160px);
  background-color: red;
}

#shop {
  right: calc(-100vw + 120px);
  background-color: blue;
}

#spot.open {
  right: 80px;
}

#rencontres.open {
  right: 40px;
}

#shop.open {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spot" class="tab">

  <div class="tab_title">

  </div>

</div>

<div id="rencontres" class="tab">

  <div class="tab_title">

  </div>

</div>

<div id="shop" class="tab">

  <div class="tab_title">

  </div>

</div>
```